# Expand a folder in VSCode using only keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to expand a folder in the explorer of VS code only by using the keyboard? I can open files with `CTRL + P`, but how do I expand a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have focus in the explorer, you can use the arrow keys to move around.  You can open a folder with <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> or close it with <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>.  The explorer is treated as a `list` so it uses the various list navigation keys/commands.

You can shift focus from the editor to  that file in the explorer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.

As of v1.31, you can use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to expand subfolders automatically when expanding the parent folder ala:

> Expand/Collapse All
>
> Holding the `Alt` key while expanding/collapsing tree nodes will now
>   work recursively. Note that recursive expansion only works for nodes
>   previously revealed in the tree. For example, the File Explorer will
>   not automatically expand folders which were never expanded before by
>   the user.

Comment: Pefect, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) extension, one can also navigate between directories in explorer using `j` and `k`, and expand and collapse a directory with `l` and `h` or you can press `l` once again to collapse a directory when have expanded a directory.